# facebook php sdk error - An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('1578373582426403', 'CENSORED');
$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession('1578373582426403', 'CENSORED');

$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');

$response = $request->execute();

$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

when `$request->execute()` is called, i get the error:

> An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

Im not sure what im doing wrong... can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to access the current user's information,try this. Change the redirect login

```
// Call Facebook Session- App Id, App Secret
Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('1578373582426403', 'CENSORED');

//Facebook Redirect Helper
//Create a FB variable, Pass oAuth URL
$facebook= new Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/fb/');

//
try
{
    //To check method getSessionFromRedirect
    if($session= $facebook->getSessionFromRedirect())
    {
        //store the token in a session variable
        $_SESSION['facebook']=$session->getToken();
    }

    //If the session is already set
    if(isset($_SESSION['facebook']))
    {
        //New Facebook Session; Pass the facebook token
        $session= new \Facebook\FacebookSession($_SESSION['facebook']);

        //Creating a fb request, pass the session, method, /me to get the user's details
        $request= new \Facebook\FacebookRequest($session,'GET','/me');

        //Execute the request
        $request=$request->execute();

        $user=$request->getGraphObject()->asArray();

       // print_r($user);
    }

}
catch(Facebook\FacebookRequestException $e)
{
    //When FB returns an error
}
catch(\Exception $e)
{
    //Normal exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting up a session, using an App Access token. That means that the access token *only* identifies your app; no users.

The call you are making, `/me`, is an alias for the current *user* ID of the used access token. But, there is no user ID for an app. And, with just an App Access token you can't request user information.

To make your script work, you should query `/1578373582426403`, which is the App ID.

Update: you can also query `/app`, which should be the alias for the app of an access token.